# Eclipse: adt was unable to instantiate class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor

Tags: java, android, layout, adt

while developing with Eclipse, and trying to install hibernate, storm and some other ORM / DAO generator tools, the eclipse stopped working properly.

I had two kind of error:
1 while building it said "Running android lint error". I solve this error unistalling and reinstalling the ADT plugin
2 while opening xml files (layout and not). I still have this issue.

**while opening any .xml files from the res folder it gives me:**
Error log:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.7.0_06
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

Error
Thu Feb 21 12:48:55 CET 2013
Plug-in "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt" was unable to instantiate class "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor".

org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Plug-in "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt" was unable to instantiate class "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor".
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.throwException(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:194)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ExtensionRegistry.createExecutableExtension(ExtensionRegistry.java:905)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElement.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElement.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.ConfigurationElementHandle.createExecutableExtension(ConfigurationElementHandle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPlugin.createExtension(WorkbenchPlugin.java:265)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.registry.EditorDescriptor.createEditor(EditorDescriptor.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:283)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPart(CompatibilityPart.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPart(CompatibilityEditor.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:286)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:859)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:839)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:896)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4687)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.delegateBringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.bringToTop(PartServiceImpl.java:315)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.showPart(PartServiceImpl.java:985)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3079)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$22(WorkbenchPage.java:3003)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2985)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2981)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2940)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2931)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:655)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: class com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidSourceViewerConfig overrides final method getContentAssistant.(Lorg/eclipse/jface/text/source/ISourceViewer;)Lorg/eclipse/jface/text/contentassist/IContentAssistant;
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.defineClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClassHoldingLock(ClasspathManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:607)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:492)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.loader.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:465)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.findLocalClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at
...
```

**while opening any files in the project root (classpath, factorypath, manifest etc...) is gives me:**

first error:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.7.0_06
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

Error
Thu Feb 21 13:02:28 CET 2013
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3095)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$22(WorkbenchPage.java:3003)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$8.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2985)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2981)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2940)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2931)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:655)
    at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:614)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:376)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:864)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1152)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1029)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:923)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:588)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

second error:

```
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.7.0_06
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=it_IT
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64

Error
Thu Feb 21 13:02:28 CET 2013
Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui".

java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.eclipse.wst.xml.core.internal.modelquery.ModelQueryUtil.getModelQuery(Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;)Lorg/eclipse/wst/xml/core/internal/contentmodel/modelquery/ModelQuery;" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, org/eclipse/wst/xml/ui/internal/DOMObserver, and the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) for resolved class, org/eclipse/wst/xml/core/internal/modelquery/ModelQueryUtil, have different Class objects for the type elQueryUtil.getModelQuery(Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;)Lorg/eclipse/wst/xml/core/internal/contentmodel/modelquery/ModelQuery; used in the signature
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.DOMObserver.<init>(DOMObserver.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.registry.AdapterFactoryProviderForXML.addContentBasedFactories(AdapterFactoryProviderForXML.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.registry.AdapterFactoryProviderForXML.addAdapterFactories(AdapterFactoryProviderForXML.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.editor.EditorModelUtil$1.run(EditorModelUtil.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.Platform.run(Platform.java:857)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.internal.editor.EditorModelUtil.addFactoriesTo(EditorModelUtil.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.doSetInput(StructuredTextEditor.java:1665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor$19.run(AbstractTextEditor.java:3209)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow$13.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1675)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:1672)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.internalInit(AbstractTextEditor.java:3227)
    at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.AbstractTextEditor.init(AbstractTextEditor.java:3254)
    at org.eclipse.wst.sse.ui.StructuredTextEditor.init(StructuredTextEditor.java:2049)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.addPage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart.addSourcePage(XMLMultiPageEditorPart.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.wst.xml.ui.internal.tabletree.XMLMultiPageEditorPart.createPages(XMLMultiPageEditorPart.java:493)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.createPartControl(CompatibilityPart.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityEditor.createPartControl(CompatibilityEditor.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityPart.create(CompatibilityPart.java:300)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor39.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:859)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:839)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer.createWidget(ContributedPartRenderer.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createWidget(PartRenderingEngine.java:896)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.safeCreateGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:732)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.access$2(PartRenderingEngine.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$7.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:697)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.createGui(PartRenderingEngine.java:682)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$1.handleEvent(PartServiceImpl.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4687)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:58)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.ElementContainerImpl.setSelectedElement(ElementContainerImpl.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.showElementInWindow(ModelServiceImpl.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ModelServiceImpl.bringToTop(ModelServiceImpl.java:385)
        at 
...
```

**what I have tried:**

1. reinstalling the java jre and jdk. Now I have installed both version
   (6 and 7) with both architecture type (x86, x64).
2. changing the environment variables from jre6 to jr7 bin
3. uninstall all the ORM tools I have installed (I still have them
   uninstalled at the moment).
4. googling so much, trying to find a solution (I also have found some
   similar answer here in sof but they have not been usefull for my
   issue).
5. clean the project and restared eclipse so many times.
6. Updated the ADT and checked installed plugin updates.

I am very open to give you all the information you would need.

Comment: have you solve your above query ?

Answer (score 22):

*This question has been asked a few times ago, however I stumbled upon it after running into some pretty similar stack, so an answer may still be useful:*

Just starting eclipse with the `-clean` option managed to get everything back on track.
It's always worth trying before starting to delete plugin folders or rebuild a workspace from scratch.

Comment: I resolved the issue by restarting the computer. Anyway I found your tip very usefull. Thank you